# Use right-click with Windows Forms Button

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, events, button

I am writing an app where the user should be able to alter the action of a button.

The user should right-click a button, and choose an option from a pop-up context menu.  Once the choice has been made the button will perform a different action when the user uses a normal click.

I've already gotten the "Click" event working for a normal button click, however the "MouseClick" event handler isn't working correctly.

The "MouseClick" event gets activated on regular left-clicks, but never get's called for right-click.

Is there some default event handling being performed that is ignoring that right-click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display a context menu with actions to choose from it should be enough to assign a `ContextMenuStrip` to the [`ContextMenuStrip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.contextmenustrip.aspx) property. There is usually no need to manually handle the mouse events for that.

Comment: another SO post might be of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044883/custom-user-control-in-c-right-click-menu-to-copy-text-java-developer-learnin

Comment: Thanks.  I'll use this method.  As a side-note, I did just find that the "MouseUp" event was the one I should have been looking at.

Comment: @birdlips: the memory is short, but on the other hand it was nearly 20 days ago :o)

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to say that this would be a serious UI blooper. Perhaps it would make more sense to add a small combobox next to the button.

Perhaps something like this?
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/SplitButton.aspx

Comment: I agree, very non-standard and confusing.  Poor design IMO.

Comment: @Ed - Well, my idea is actually very much like the solution posted in Zyphrax's link, so I don't think it's so terribly non-standard and confusing.  However, the linked solution is a little more obvious and elegant than mine, so I'll probably go that direction if it makes sense in future applications.

Answer (score 3):

surely it would be better to implement it on the MouseDown event rather than the MouseUp event. i dont understand how this is much different from MouseClick event

edit: Just tried this and it works a treat :)

Answer (score 2):

In Button (and certain other controls), the MouseClick event is only fired for the left button. Refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542.aspx).

If you want to know about the right button, respond to the MouseUp event--though as other posters have pointed out, this isn't a great UI idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Mouse UP event... test that Button.X and Button.Y are within the size of the button otherwise you have moved the mouse away from the button.
Terry G